# Extract data from XML file to MS excel using vba

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Hi i have an xml response from an API,  i want to extract the  data from xml file to excel, but all the fields are in section.
I am a beginner in XML, and i am not able to extract data from  section. I have tried to write some code but none have succeeded.

I have written some code but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want is a separate XML document embedded in the CDATA section of the response XML.

You need to extract the XML and load it in a second document object so you can extract the data you want.

For example:

```vb
    Sub Test()
        
        'Tools->References->Microsoft Xml v.60
        Dim dom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, childDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Dim recXML As String, rec, recs
        
        Set dom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set childDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        
        dom.Load "C:\Users\Tim\OneDrive\Desktop\temp\response.xml"
        
        'you need to set up the namespace property
        dom.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:abc='http://www.isinet.com/xrpc42'"
        
        Dim xmlSomeCData As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
        'use the namspace alias we created earlier when querying
        Set xmlSomeCData = dom.SelectSingleNode("abc:response/abc:map/abc:map/abc:val")
    
        recXML = xmlSomeCData.Text '<<< the text in the CDATA section is the source XML
                                   '    to be loaded into ChildDoc
        childDoc.LoadXML recXML
        'select some nodes from the embedded xml document....
        Set recs = childDoc.SelectNodes("//records/REC/UID")
        Debug.Print recs.Length
        For Each rec In recs
            Debug.Print rec.Text
        Next rec
    
    End Sub
```